# How can I disable the white color in JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtabbedpane

I am trying to customize `Colors` in a `JTabbedPane`. I've tried everything and nothing seems to work. I need to change the white color in the image.
Please help.
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0n4D.png)

and this is my code

```java
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentBorderInsets", new InsetsUIResource(2, 0, 0, 0));//border 
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentAreaColor",new Color(158, 112, 93));//selected border color
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.darkShadow", new Color(107, 76, 63));//not selected border color
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.light", new Color(107, 76, 63));
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.borderHightlightColor", new Color(158, 112, 93));//border color
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", new Color(107, 76, 63));//selected tab color
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selectHighlight", new Color(158, 112, 93));
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.focus",new Color(107, 76, 63));//focus color
```

Comment: Can you specify the look&feel that you're using?

Comment: @Rocco metal look&feel

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but perhaps you can try `ColorUIResource` like this:

```java
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentAreaColor", new ColorUIResource(new Color(158, 112, 93)));
```